# IE9 <a> works in directly loaded page but not working when coming via linked page

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain

This question does not need a cross-browser solution as the pages will be exclusively used by IE9.

With that said, I have a page ( *myPage* ) being developed that accesses a page from a different domain ( *linkedPage*). Within the linkedPage there is a PDF attachment ( *pdfAttachment* ).

*myPage* URL: `http://myDomain/files/myPage.html`

*linkedPage* URL: `https://na13.salesforce.com/article/x.html`

*pdfAttachment* URL: `https://c.na13.content.force.com/servlet/x.pdf`

When a user triggers the opening of the *linkedPage* via window.open:

```
window.open('https://na13.salesforce.com/article/x.html', '_blank', 'toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=300, left=500, width=1000, height=600');
```

and then clicks on the link for the .pdf attachment,

```
<a href="https://c.na13.content.force.com/servlet/x.pdf" target="_blank">Load x.pdf</a>
```

it returns the error

> Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.

However, if the user loads the *linkedPage* directly (versus from a link on *myPage*), the *pdfAttachment* loads without issue.

I do not have control over the *linkedPage* or *pdfAttachment* pages but it may be possible to have the group that does control those host *myPage* as well as a last resort.

Is this a cross-domain issue? I'm not trying to run scripts or manipulate the content so with my less than robust understanding of that, it doesn't seem to fit.

Are there settings for IE9 that could be causing the issue?

I feel like it might be related to the window.open but was unable to find anything here or through other sites.  Does window.open put any limitations on the page it loads?

What other possible things could be causing this issue?

Thanks to all!

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

When troubleshooting this, I discovered that I was able to access *linkedPage* from *myPage* and open *pdfAttachment* successfully on a system with full internet access while the majority of its users will have limited internet access to whitelisted items only (of which both the *linkedPage* and *pdfAttachment* are).

Also, when users access the *linkedPage* by itself (not from *myPage*) they login through Citrix and then login to Salesforce.  When the *linkedPage* is accessed from *myPage* they are only prompted to login to Salesforce.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference, since systems with full internet access are still successful without first going through Citrix.

Could there be any permission issues?!

@jdu - here is the markup

```
<body>
 <div class="knowledgePrintableView" id="knowledgePrintableView">
  <div id="articlePrintableView:j_id3:j_id4:j_id24">
   <div class="knowledgePrintableViewContent " id="knowledgePrintableViewContent">
    <div class="sectionContent">
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td class="fieldValue">
        <span id="articleX">
         <div>
           <img src="/sfc/images/docicons/doctype_pdf_16.png" alt="PDF" title="PDF" />
           <!-- Only the text node exists within the <a> tag -->
           <a href="https://c.na13.content.force.com/servlet/fileField?id=pdfAttachment" target="_blank">PDF Attachment.pdf</a>
         </div>
        </span>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you share (jsfiddle.net) the HTML for this page: https://na13.salesforce.com/article/x.html

Comment: perhaps you can use the google docs viewer? It is extremely simple to use and takes care of most browser issues. https://docs.google.com/viewer

Comment: @jdu - unfortunately I don't think I can because the _linkedPage_ and _pdfAttachment_ require credentials to access.

Comment: if you view source and copy/paste to pastebin...  I want to see the markup used around your <a> tag,  as IE (particularly older versions) are pretty picky about using valid/correct markup for anchor tags.   basically don't wrap a bunch of other elements in an anchor.

Comment: @khuderm - I'm not sure that will work because they ( the _linkedPage_ and _pdfAttachment_ ) deal with proprietary information.

Comment: @jdu - I've added the markup to the post.  The `<a>` tag has only the text node within and has `<img>` as its only sibling.

Answer (score 0):

> When troubleshooting this, I discovered that I was able to access
>   linkedPage from myPage and open pdfAttachment successfully on a system
>   with full internet access while the majority of its users will have
>   limited internet access to whitelisted items only (of which both the
>   linkedPage and pdfAttachment are).

Hmmm!  Then I would focus your search there.  You're using an HTTPS link in that anchor tag, and trying to route through some other systems.  Those other systems may not allow HTTPS traffic.

Try a non-secure link.